# Subquery with multiple sorted results

Tags: sql, ms-access

Struggling on a most probably very simple query for MS Access, but couldn't nail it for 3 days already.

Any help would be highly appreciated..

There are 2 tables - Regions (REGNAME) and Cities (REGNAME, NAME, POPULATION)

I need to get the top 10 cities sorted by the population in descending order for each region.

There's no problem to do this for some certain Region:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Cities.REGNAME, NAME from Cities, Regions 
WHERE Cities.REGNAME = Regions.REGNAME 
AND Regions.REGNAME = 'SOME_REGION_NAME' 
ORDER BY POPULATION DESC
```

But I need to see the similar list of Cities for any number of Regions. 
For every region in subquery I should see sorded 10 cities' list.

Like below:

```
SOME_REGION_NAME - CITY 1
SOME_REGION_NAME - CITY 2
SOME_REGION_NAME - ..
SOME_REGION_NAME - CITY 10

ANOTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 1
ANOTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 2
ANOTHER_REGION_NAME - ..
ANOTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 10

SOME_OTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 1
SOME_OTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 2
SOME_OTHER_REGION_NAME - ..
SOME_OTHER_REGION_NAME - CITY 10
```

This query gives 10 cities in total from 3 regions:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Cities.REGNAME, NAME from Cities, Regions 
WHERE Cities.REGNAME = Regions.REGNAME 
AND Regions.REGNAME IN ('SOME_REGION_NAME' , 'ANOTHER_REGION_NAME', 'SOME_OTHER_REGION_NAME')
ORDER BY POPULATION DESC
```

But I expect to see a 30 cities table, not 10.

Please, someone, show me the way :)

Thank you

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Tip 2: Store region id in the cities table, not region name.

Comment: @jarlh, yes, there are ids and name in the tables, but for the sake of simplicity of my example I decided to show names only. In fact, tables will be joined on ids at production:) But how to join exactly? ..

Comment: Great to hear. Unfortunately (?) I don't know MS Access very well, so I'm afraid I can't assist you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to select the top 10 cities for each region:

```
SELECT R.REGNAME, C.NAME, C.POPULATION
FROM Cities AS C INNER JOIN Regions AS R ON C.REGNAME = R.REGNAME
WHERE C.NAME IN (SELECT TOP 10 [NAME] FROM Cities AS C1 WHERE C1.REGNAME=R.REGNAME ORDER BY C1.POPULATION DESC)
ORDER BY R.REGNAME ASC, C.POPULATION DESC
```

You may get more than 10 cities being returned for a region if there is a tie on the population.

Note that as well as it being better to use a foreign key to store the region in the cities table, `NAME` is a reserved word in Access, so you should rename the field - in the example SQL, I've just wrapped it in square brackets.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you, @Applecore, but this didn't work for me, although it looks very promising. So what I get is the full list with cities, similar to that, if i run the query without line 3 from your snippet.

Comment: So sorry, it seems OK now! I have mixed NAME and REGNAME in one place.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, this is often handled using `IN` with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ci.REGNAME, ci.NAME 
FROM Cities as ci
WHERE ci.NAME IN (SELECT TOP 10 ci2.Name
                  FROM Cities as ci2
                  ORDER BY ci.POPULATION DESC
                 )
ORDER BY ci.REGNAME, ci.POPULATION DESC;
```

Notice that this does not require the `Regions` table.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks! Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Becides, I really need 'Regions' table in my final query, cause I get some more info from that table (not mentioned in my question for the sake of simplicity). So preferable to have some joins with it too..

Comment: "didn't work for me" is pretty vague.  This answers the question that you *asked*.  If you actually need the regions table, you can always join it in as well.